# Is there any function in Java which is equivalent to shift() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

I am writing a java function which is inspired from a javascript project.
This function along with other helper functions is used to convert an SDP to an XML.

Javascript code :

```
parseRTCPFB(line) {
    const parts = line.substr(10).split(' ');
    const data = {};

    data.pt = parts.shift();
    data.type = parts.shift();
    data.params = parts;

    return data;
}
```

In the above snippet parts is an array and the shift function is being used on it.
According to my understanding the shift function, pops and returns the first element.

Any similar function that operates on ArrayList in java?
Thank you

Comment: Like [`removeFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeFirst())?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Oh nice, since Java 21, I need to update myself. Without that, you can use `.remove(0)` I suppose.

Comment: @sp00m in case you're using an older version `remove(0)` works just fine.

Comment: If Java 21 turns out problematic, using `LinkedList`, which implements `Queue` and therefore `poll()`, should also work.

Comment: `String[] data = line.substring(10).split(" ", 2);` will give you a three-element array

Comment: @sp00m the method has been added because of the [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html) abstraction.

Comment: But removing from the beginning of a list can be very inefficient. You can simply use an `Iterator` to process the first elements one by one and if you want to process the remainder as a `List`, there’s [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#subList(int,int)). Don’t try to shoehorn the idioms of a different programming language over Java.